# How to index a particular date from my variable

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to index the date row having the following date `'2019-10-31'` from my variable `date_output_ts` . Not sure what I am doing wrong

```
testing = date_output_ts.index[date_output_ts.dt(2019, 10, 31, 0, 0)].tolist()
testing
```

Comment: What is `print (date_output_ts)` ?